# Some Button.attributes Missing In a foreach Control loop

Tags: c#

When using a `foreach` loop to change controls' attributes I often find that certain attributes are missing.

If I say `btnMyButton`. I can then select `".SelectedForeColor"` from intellisense.

However, if I say `foreach(Control x in this.Controls)` or, `foreach(Button x in this.Controls)`, the attribute `".SelectedForeColor"` is missing from intellisense.

```
//This Works

        btnMyButton.SelectedForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

This Does Not Work. The attribute is not available

```
        foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
        {                
            if (x is Button)
            {
                ((Button)x).SelectedForeColor = Color.Blue;                    
            }
        }
```

Any thoughts on how to set `Control.SelectedForeColor` via a `foreach` loop would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your for loop to this:

```
foreach (Buttonx in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
```

Then, you'll have the correct type and your properties are available.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are directly using the variable the Button was assigned to, which is of type Button.

In the foreach you are iterating over a **collection of Controls**. While the Buttons can "fit" into the control type, you only got access to Control properties and functions. This is just 101 of class behavior, section Polymorphy.

So these two examples are not even remotely similar scenarios. You either need to only retrieve buttons to iterate over (which should get you a collection of button instances), or continue to do the check+cast you are already doing.

A third option is to create your own collection of buttons to iterate over, using the names you already got something like:

```
Button[] ArrayOfButtons = { btnMyButton, btnCancel, btnOK, btnAccept };
```